# Why does VS 2010 show this warning triangle in Win7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Can anyone tell me why I keep seeing this warning icon on the taskbar? I can't figure it out.

[image: VS 2010 Warning Triangle]

Comment: Did any of your projects or solutions have any warnings? Are there any updates you haven't installed? Do you see any messages from VS in the tray?

Comment: It is not VS that does this.  Some other "helpful" program on your machine adds the icon overlay.  Maybe because you've got VS running in admin mode.  Maybe your anti-malware got excited about an exe that appeared from nowhere.  Ask at superuser.com

Comment: Jeff: No build-warnings or pending installs.

Comment: Hans: It IS running as Administrator, but I do not have an antivirus installed.

Comment: FYI: when replying to people, it should be in the form @Jason ([see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)), otherwise we will not know that there was a reply (I just happened to refresh the page and saw your comment).

Answer (score 0):

The [Win7 Taskbar Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c92dd87-50ac-489e-882b-b99de7624502/) adds Warnings/Errors overlay icons to the taskbar.